# PHP get the site that calls your script via file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents, referrer

I have a PHP script hosted on my site that outputs a value based on the GET parameters passed.

Other sites call this script from within their own PHP scripts via the PHP function file_get_contents with the url and get params and are served back just the value requested.

I am trying to allow only certain domains access to this script and have been using HTTP_REFERER to check who's calling the script.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) // check if referrer is set
{
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; // echo referrer
}
else
{
    echo 'No referrer set'; // echo failure message
}
```

I am getting No referrer set when I use file_get_contents but if I use a clicked link from a page to a script with the above code the referrer displays correctly.

Am I using the wrong function (file_get_contents) to call the external script and can someone suggest the correct one or should this work?

Any help much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Bear in mind that the HTTP "Referer" header is an optional header -- there's no need for a site to send it to you, and it can be easily faked. If you really only want certain people to use your resources, you're better off using some form of authentication.

Comment: file_get_contents by default is a completely independent/brand new request. There would be no referer, since no page referred that connection. If you want it to send a referer header, you'd have to set up a stream context: http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would be much better to restrict based on IP address rather than domain, much more reliable. Just keep an array of allowed IP's and call `in_array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],$allowedAddresses)` to validate it.

Or just require authentication via a cookie or HTTP auth...

Comment: Agreed. Referrer should never be used for security. It is unreliable, easily manipulated, and often disabled completely by browsers.

Comment: This works okay as long as you're okay allowing anyone on that IP to connect, and assuming your IPs won't change. Shared hosting services might allow a hundred different "domains" to connect from a single IP address, plus if your real customer moves hosting, you'll have to update the IP. So, consider those problems if you choose to lock down by IP.

Comment: @Matt I know - I suppose you could extend this with reverse DNS lookups ([`gethostbyaddr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyaddr.php)) but that would slow script execution, requires properly configured rDNS and still doesn't fix the shared hosting problem. But if you restrict by domain it is so ridiculously easy to spoof no matter how you do it that it's just not worth the bother. I think requiring some kind of auth is the only practical approach, but I thought I'd mention the IP approach anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using this solution now. - EDIT all these came as I wrote, yes certainly dynamic IPs may be a pickle. Have looked into resolve ip to domain and seems a lot of the servers are generic hosts. I'll keep an eye on their IP's to see if they're static or not. There may well not be enough users of the script to worry about ambiguous hosts however. Thanks all.

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that the HTTP "[Referer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)" header is an optional header -- there's no need for a site to send it to you, and it can be easily faked. If you really only want certain people to use your resources, you're better off using some form of authentication.

Typically Referer: is sent by web browsers, but there's no need for it to be -- for example, they won't send it if the referer is a secure site. With a PHP `file_get_contents()` there isn't technically a referer anyway; you're not being "referred" from anywhere.

Consider instead either:

- Locking down by IP address (but bear in mind that multiple domains can share a single IP, and that a domain's IP can change.)
- Using some form of authentication (preferably *not* one that transmits passwords in plain text!)

You should consider how secure you need this service to be, and what threats might attack it when deciding the right security to apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using HTTP_REFERER.

The HTTP_REFERER it set by the client, and it can be anything the client wants.

You have to use a password / key authentication mechanism instead.

Comment: Thanks very much, understood. Would that key not be embedded in any script on their server and possibly then be able to be spoofed by a future developer? Just a thought is all.

Comment: obviously the key has to be secret

Comment: Well would the key not sit inside the calling websites script and not be secret? The calling site must know the key and my point is what's to stop they key being passed to other sites? Else how might such secrecy be maintained given the scenario. Just curious is all. Cheers.

Comment: you should give a different key to each allowed user, and not embed it in the scripts you distribute

Answer (score 0):

May want to use something along the lines of a stream context to set extra headers.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php

Additionally, if needed, you could set a 'secret' header to authenticate the requests, rather then the referer.

Comment: Proxies tend to strip headers they don't recognise, which will break the secret header idea - nice thought though...

Comment: In case there is a proxy, a cookie header could be used in the request, or one of another dozen different standard authentication methods instead.